# Stacked bar charts with percentages

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a stacked bar chart to show the adjusted percentages of specific data per country. Basically, I would like to adjust the bar charts to fit the percentages? Also how can change the number to percentages (eg. instead of -0.02 to show -2%?

**Sample code:**

```
df$Country<- factor(df$Country,levels = c( "Australia","Austria", "Belgium","Canada","Denmark","Finland",
                                           "France","Germany","Greece","Iceland","Ireland","Italy",
                                           "Japan", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands","New Zealand","Norway","Portugal", 
                                           "Spain" ,"Sweden","Switzerland","Turkey", "United Kingdom", "United States" ))


df$Data<- factor(df$Data,levels = c("TED 2003 (adjusted)", "OECD 2003 (adjusted)"))


(plot<-ggplot(df, aes(x=THW, y=Country, fill=Data,label = THW)) +  
    geom_bar( stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(size = 4,  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="black", fontface="bold")+
    #facet_wrap(~Country, scales = "free")+
    labs(x="Average hours worked per civilian employee in 2003", y="", title="", fill="Data source:" )+
    theme_bw()+
    
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = , hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
          axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          strip.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
          legend.position="right",
          legend.box = "vertical",
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    scale_y_discrete()+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()))
```

**Sample data 1 (totals):**

```
   df<-structure(list(Country = structure(c(17L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 14L, 
5L, 21L, 20L, 12L, 3L, 23L, 6L, 11L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 19L, 
10L, 24L, 9L, 22L, 17L, 15L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 14L, 5L, 21L, 20L, 12L, 
3L, 23L, 6L, 11L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 4L, 19L, 10L, 24L, 9L, 22L
), .Label = c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Denmark", 
"Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Iceland", "Ireland", 
"Italy", "Japan", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Norway", "Portugal", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", 
"United Kingdom", "United States"), class = "factor"), THW = c(-0.05, 
-0.06, -0.05, 0.01, -0.19, -0.04, 0.04, -0.08, -0.02, -0.13, 
0.03, -0.03, -0.04, -0.14, -0.11, -0.04, -0.02, -0.04, 0.01, 
0.02, 0.09, 0.01, -0.08, -0.01, -0.04, -0.06, -0.05, 0, -0.2, 
-0.04, 0.04, -0.08, 0.08, -0.13, 0.01, 0.05, 0.01, -0.14, -0.02, 
-0.04, -0.02, -0.02, 0.01, 0.03, 0.09, 0.01, -0.04, -0.01), Data = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("TED 2003 (adjusted)", 
"OECD 2003 (adjusted)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-48L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), THW = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Data = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


**Output**
```

[image]

Comment: Some of your `THW` variable are just `integer` numbers, and some of them are numbers with `%`. Is that something you really want?

Comment: What do you mean by "adjust the bar charts to fit the percentages"? `position='fill'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation:

With ggplot 2.1.0, geom_text has position_fill / position_stack, Therefore, there is no longer a need to calculate nor use the y aesthetic pos to position the labels.

1. add a `label` column to your dataframe:
   `df1 <- df %>%  mutate(label = paste0(THW*100, "%"))`
2. Then I changed x and y and used `coord_flip()` at the end. I think this is more logic. At least for me.
3. Add `aes(label = label)` to `geom_text` like:
   `geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 3,  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="black", fontface="bold") +`

Full code:

```
df$Country<- factor(df$Country,levels = c( "Australia","Austria", "Belgium","Canada","Denmark","Finland",
                                           "France","Germany","Greece","Iceland","Ireland","Italy",
                                           "Japan", "Luxembourg", "Netherlands","New Zealand","Norway","Portugal", 
                                           "Spain" ,"Sweden","Switzerland","Turkey", "United Kingdom", "United States" ))


df$Data<- factor(df$Data,levels = c("TED 2003 (adjusted)", "OECD 2003 (adjusted)"))

df1 <- df %>%  mutate(label = paste0(THW*100, "%"))

(plot<-ggplot(df1, aes(x=Country, y=THW, fill=Data,label = THW)) +  
    geom_bar( stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 3,  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),color="black", fontface="bold") +
    #facet_wrap(~Country, scales = "free")+
    labs(x="Average hours worked per civilian employee in 2003", y="", title="", fill="Data source:" )+
    theme_bw()+
    
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = , hjust = 1,family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
          axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          strip.text = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          legend.text = element_text(family="Times", color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
          legend.position="right",
          legend.box = "vertical",
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    scale_x_discrete()+
    coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()))
```

[image]